# Where is the Google-drive-sdk issues list

Tags: google-drive-api

Where is the list of google-drive-sdk issues/bugs etc.

I was expecting a 2min google search would find it. But this is the best I can find.
https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/issues/list

I have been searching for about 20min, still not found it.

Comment: may I humbly suggest that you un-accept my answer in the hope that the open question gets a more definitive response from a Googler.

Comment: Done. I should have waited longer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four categories of issue:-

- Drive. No public issues list afaik
- Drive API. No public issues list afaik
- Drive client libraries. They sometimes exists, such http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/list for the Java client
- Service interruptions. No formal status reporting, but the Drive Developers Community on G+ is a good starting point as issues get flagged by developers pretty quickly.

Comment: Your AFAIK is as good as mine (maybe some unstructured info @ https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos - issues) But instead of AFAIK 'there is nothing', shouldn't this question be considered a message to Google Play Svcs / Google Drive folks to give us some guidance (and I don't know if you work for one of the teams)

Comment: You're right @seanpj. It's been raised before stackoverflow.com/questions/12106497/… and stackoverflow.com/questions/18583885/… . I've added a fourth item to the list, dealing with production service issues.

Comment: Yep, although SO is a great platform with a broad audience, the accountability and tracking is questionable. And I never know if I'm dealing with the Google engineer responsible for the problem or with somebody like myself who has no impact on the solution.